# Rails ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, has-many-through, join

I have been setting up a cart model in my rails app when this error occurred. The associations are supposed to be that a User can have one Cart, a Cart belongs to a User and can have many Parts(items). Theres a many-to-many relationship between Parts and Carts since multiple users can have one cart. I create a join table called CartsParts which has a cart_id and a part_id.

Heres my Part model

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :carts, through: :carts_parts
  belongs_to :category
```

Cart model

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :parts, through: :carts_parts
end
```

My Join Table CartsParts

```
class CreateCartsParts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :carts, :parts do |t|
      t.index [:cart_id, :part_id]
      t.index [:part_id, :cart_id]
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting the error stating "Could not find the association :carts_parts in model Cart", even though I set up the has_many through relationship. I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Do you have `CartsPart` model defined in `app/models/carts_part.rb`?

Comment: yes I do this is my model for CartsPart

class CartsParts < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts
  has_many :carts
end

Comment: In that case you also need to have `has_many :carts_parts, class_name: 'CartsParts'` in both your `Cart` and `Part` models. By convention you should name your `CartsParts` model `CartsPart`, or better yet `CartPart` else you'd need to define the `class_name: 'CartsParts'` for `has_many` relationship.

Comment: yep thats fixed it thanks!